# project euler 14 using the state monad

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to teach myself Haskell (again) by working through Project Euler.  Question 14 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=14) is begging for dynamic programming and historically I've been vehemently anti-monad (on account of repeatedly failing to learn to use them well enough to make life easier instead of harder) so I'm trying to bite the bullet and use the State monad to memoize my code... it's not going well.  I want to be clear, I've already solved the problem the easy/slow way, at this point I'm trying to learn something (ie [Project Euler No. 14 Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534989/project-euler-no-14-haskell) is not what I'm looking for).

My code so far is:

```
collatzMemoCheck :: Int -> State (Map Int Int) Int
collatzMemoCheck n = state $ \s -> maybe (let (a, s') = runState (collatzFast n) s
                                          in (a+1, Map.insert n (a+1) s'))
                                         (\len -> (len, s))
                                         (Map.lookup n s)

collatzFast :: Int -> State (Map Int Int) Int
collatzFast 1 = state $ \_ -> (1, Map.singleton 1 1)
collatzFast n
  | even n    = collatzMemoCheck (n `quot` 2)
  | otherwise = collatzMemoCheck (3 * n + 1)
```

which works for individual queries in cabal repl, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to chain up the state of repeated calls to collatzFast.  I want something like

```
-- DOES NOT WORK
allCollatzLengths = scanl (>>= collatzFast) (return Map.empty) [1..999999]
```

but I think this is inside out.  Bind takes the result portion of the previous State computation and passes it to the next call, but I want it to take the state portion of the previous State computation and pass *it* to the next call.

Is there a right way to do this or have I painted myself into a corner?  If I can't use >>=, what's the point of having a monad?  ... or is there no point because this is a stupid approach?  Help?

Comment: I'll note that using State is not the idiomatic way to memoize in Haskell, neither is it the way to get elegant DP. This question you're referring to as the "easy/slow way" does in fact have quite a few answers that use the idiomatic DP way to achieve very good performance... Do you want to use State to learn how to use it or are you more interested by efficient DP in Haskell ?

Comment: Both, but the other way was already covered pretty well.  Do you have a sense for why this isn't idiomatic?Edit: also, I wasn't referring that question as being the easy/slow way, I was referring to a naive non-DP implementation as the easy/slow way.

Comment: just out of curiosity: what would be an acceptable speed for you? I simple (non-monadic) version where I am passing a strict Map around runs in 4.5sec on my rig - is this to slow for you?

Comment: My slow version doesn't even involve a map,  it's simply  collatzSlow :: Int -> [Int]    and then  maximum $ map (\a -> (length $ collatzSlow a, a)) [1..999999].  Edit:  It seems the reason my naive code was slow was that I was running it in the repl.  cabal repl it took 128.5 seconds, but cabal run took merely 1.5 seconds

Comment: Woah, that's interesting, the fast version (as enabled by Daniel) takes 18 sec in the repl and 2.8 with a regular run!  Why the naive version is faster in run mode I don't even begin to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might like

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

In particular, `mapM collatzFast :: [Int] -> State (Map Int Int) [Int]`.